# Why is the cursor locked as a pencil in Adobe Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When I open an Illustrator file delivered to me, the cursor is in the form shown below:

[image]

Clicking on the Selection Tool does not change the cursor.  Why is this?
I am on Windows 10, Illustrator CC version 23.0.1.

PS: I am an Illustrator newbie.

Comment: Looks like the layer you are trying to draw on is locked.

Comment: @BillyKerr That was it, thank you.  I will accept if you post it as answer.  Regards.

Comment: OK I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem but I am very sure that no layers are locked. Anyone can help?

Comment: The little "don't" symbol essentially means "You *can't* do that here". As for *why* you can't and you aren't trying to work on a locked layer.... no one knows. Only you can figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the layer you are trying to draw on is locked.

You can either unlock the layer in the layers panel, or create a new layer.

Answer (score 0):

You must unlock at least one layer or keep visible at least one layer, for the cursor to be available.